# When adding to a HashSet in a for loop how do I remove duplicates but also replace them with another object?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashset

**Problem**

I am building an app which can create raffle draws from an arrayList of entries. When starting the draw, the user can input an integer which states how many winners the draw will return. The app uses randomGenerator to pick a random index from the entry arrayList. This randomGenerator is within a for loop which checks how many times it has been iterated over and compares it to the numberOfWinners integer.

Say the user inserted "3" as their integer for numberOfWinners. The app would return three random entries, however there are sometimes duplicates.

So naturally I researched how to avoid duplicates. I came across HashSet. If two duplicate entries are added to the HashSet, only one unique entry is added. I then converted this HashSet into a new ArrayList, and displayed it on my Android view as a ListView.

However, the HashSet has not solved the problem. If the user enters the input "3" for numberOfWinners, and there is a duplicate, the end result will only be 2 entries.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is a segment of my code:

```html
Set <Entry>drawSet = new HashSet<Entry>();


        //Picks random int from size of entry arrayList

        Intent viewDrawIntent = getIntent();
        int currentRaffleID = viewDrawIntent.getIntExtra("raffleIndexInList", 0);
        int newNoOfWinners = viewDrawIntent.getIntExtra("extraNoOfWinners", 0);
        Raffle currentRaffle = Raffle.raffleArrayList.get(currentRaffleID);
        for (int i = 1; i < (currentRaffle.getEntryArrayList().size()); i++) {
            if(i != newNoOfWinners){
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(currentRaffle.getEntryArrayList().size());
                Entry randomEntry = (currentRaffle.getEntryArrayList()).get(randomInt);

                //Adds new Entry to entryDraw Array
                drawSet.add(randomEntry);
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        ArrayList<Entry> entryDraw = new ArrayList<Entry>(drawSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by looping until the Set contains the desired numbers of winners.

Working example:

```
List<Integer> tickets = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Set<Integer> winners = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();
while (winners.size() < 3) {
    winners.add(tickets.get(random.nextInt(tickets.size())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HashSet to let you know if an index of the ArrayList has already been used.

If you want to pick 3 unique indices from the list, you initialize a HashSet to contain all the indices of the ArrayList. Then, each time you draw a random index, you check if the HashSet contains that index.

- If it does, you know that this index hasn't been used yet, and you remove it from the HashSet.
- If it doesn't, that index has already been used, so you draw a random index again.

You repeat the process until you have 3 unique indices that haven't been used before.

Comment: Is checking if it is the list already strictly necessary? Surely if you just add an existing value to a Set then it has no effect...

Comment: @Adam My suggestion is to start with a full Set (containing all indices) and remove each index once it is used, so you must know if the index is present before removing it.

Comment: The problem with that method is that if you remove the index you can't use the same arrayList for a second time, the indexes are all messed up

Comment: @user3105544 I didn't suggest to remove the index from the ArrayList. I suggested to remove it from the HashSet.